# Most common words in Text file never finished for large files

Tags: c++

My program works for small files, but if I use large files (bible, Artamenes (longest novel)) it never finishes. The program keeps using more memory. It starts with 5mb and was up to over 350 in 7 hours. Is it because it is very inefficient or am I missing something?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct Pair // create a struct for each word so it includes not only the word, but its count
{
    string word; //the inputted word, eventually
    unsigned int frequency; //count for each word

    Pair(unsigned int f, const string& w) : frequency(f), word(w) {} //create constructor

    bool operator <(const Pair& str) const //for sort
    {
        return (str.frequency < frequency);
    }
};

string rmPunct (string word)
{
    unsigned int position;
    while ((position = word.find_first_of("|.,:;\"'!¡?¿/()^[]{}\\;-_*+")) != string::npos) //remove any punctuation, etc.
        {
            word.erase(position, 1);
        }
    return word;
}

string allLower(string word) 
{
    std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower); //convert any uppercase letters to lower case
    return word;
}

int main()
{

    vector<Pair> myVector; //Create a vector of structs so I have a dynamic array (can extend)
    fstream dataFile; // create the file stream
    string fileName; // necessary to find the file
    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    dataFile.open(fileName); // open the file in input mode only (no output for safeness)

    string word; //will be each word from the file
    while (dataFile >> word) // the >> imports each word until it hits a space then loops again
    {
        word = rmPunct(word);
        word = allLower(word);
        Pair *p = new Pair(1,word);
        myVector.push_back(*p); // pushes each newly created struct into the vector

        if (dataFile.fail())
            break; //stop when the file is done
    }
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<myVector.size();i++)  //this double for-loop finds each word that was already found
    {           
        for (unsigned int j = i+1;j<myVector.size();)
        {
            if (myVector[i].word == myVector[j].word) //simple comparing to find where the extra word lies
            {
                myVector.at(i).frequency++; //increment the count
                myVector.erase(myVector.begin()+j);//and... delete the duplicate struct (which has the word in it)
            }
            else
                j++;
        }
    }

    sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end());
    ofstream results;
    results.open("results.txt");
    if (myVector.size() >= 60) //outputs the top 60 most common words
    {
        for (int i=0;i<60;i++) {
            double percent = ((double)myVector[i].frequency/(double)myVector.size()*100);
            results << (i+1) << ". '" << myVector[i].word << "' occured " << myVector[i].frequency << " times.   " <<  percent << "%" << '\n';
        }
    }
    else //if there are not 60 unique words in the file
        for (unsigned int i=0;i<myVector.size(); i++)
        {
            double percent = ((double)myVector[i].frequency/(double)myVector.size()*100);
            results << (i+1) << ". '" << myVector[i].word << "' occured " << myVector[i].frequency << " times.   " <<  percent << "%" << '\n';
        } 
    results.close();
}
```

Comment: Using a name (`Pair`) very similar to a standard structure ([`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)) is kind of confusing, especially since since you are pulling in the name `pair` in the global name-space *and* you could just as easily use `std::pair` instead of your custom structure.

Answer (score 2):

This loop:

```
for (unsigned int i=0;i<myVector.size();i++)  //this double for-loop finds each word that was already found
{           
    for (unsigned int j = i+1;j<myVector.size();)
    {
        if (myVector[i].word == myVector[j].word) //simple comparing to find where the extra word lies
        {
            myVector.at(i).frequency++; //increment the count
            myVector.erase(myVector.begin()+j);//and... delete the duplicate struct (which has the word in it)
        }
        else
            j++;
    }
}
```

walks your words n^2 times (roughly). If we assume your 5MB file contains half a million words, thats 500000 * 500000 = 250 billion iterations, which will take some time to run through [and erasing words will "shuffle" the entire content of your vector, which is quite time-consuming it the vector is long and you shuffle an early item]

A better approach would be to build a data structure where you can quickly search through, such as a `map<std::string, int> words`, where you do `words[word]++;` when you read the words. Then search for the most common word by iterating of `words` and saving the 60 most common words [keeping a sorted list of the 60 most common...]

You could also do something clever like `min(60, words.size())` to know how many words you have.

Answer (score 1):

You have a small memory leak in your program, and as the data you read gets larger so does the number of leaks.

The code causing the memory leak:

```
Pair *p = new Pair(1,word);
myVector.push_back(*p); // pushes each newly created struct into the vector
```

Her you dynamically allocate a `Pair` structure, copy the structure to the vector, and the completely ignore the original allocated structure.

There is really no need for any dynamic allocation, or even a temporary variable, just do

```
myVector.push_back(Pair(1, word));
```

And if you have a new compiler that have C++11, then just do

```
myVector.emplace_back(1, word);
```

That should help you with part of the problem.

---

The other part is that your algorithm *is* slow, really *really* slow for large inputs.

That can be solved by using e.g. [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) (or [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) if you don't have `std::unordered_map`).

Then it becomes very simple, just use the word as the key, and the frequence as the data. Then for every word you read just do

```
frequencyMap[word]++;
```

No need for the loop-in-loop comparing words, which is what slows you down.

---

To get the 60 most frequent words, [copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) from the map into a vector using [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) with the frequency as the first member of the pair and the word as the second, [sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the vector, and simply print the 60 first entries in the vector.